# Jenkins: triggeredBy 'UpstreamCause' always evaluates to false in When condition

Tags: jenkins

In Jenkins I have an Upstream Project *A* that triggeres a Downstream Project *B*.

**Project A:**

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Hello') {
      steps {
        echo "Some message"
        build(job: 'B', wait: false)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Project B**

```
pipeline {
  agent none
  tools {
    maven "maven"
  }
 stages {
  stage('Triggered By Upstream') {
    when {
      triggeredBy "UpstreamCause"
    }
    steps {
      echo "Triggered by Upstream project"
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Here project *A* successfully triggers the project *B*. But the stage in project *B* will be skipped due to the condition in [when](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) being *False*. It seems like a bug to me. Does anyone know what's wrong in this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently there is no cause as **UpstreamCause**, but rather **BuildUpstreamCause**, which evaluates to *true* when the pipeline is triggered from an upstream project. So the *when clause* in **project B** should be written as:

```
when {
  triggeredBy "BuildUpstreamCause"
}
```

in order for the stage to be run when triggered from an upstream project.